# How to filter url text in Groovy

Tags: parsing, url, groovy

I would like to filter the content of url in groovy, but in no way can't find any guides or usage example in google, so any help is very much appreciated.

What am I trying to do is to get the information within

```
 <table class="smthng">
```

tag in the following url

```
def resultText = "http://weather.am".toURL().text
```

what I have tried so far is to find desired starting line then process each line until reaching the closing tag, but I am pretty sure Groovy should have something very nice to handle it. for instance, in groovy I can use find closure to find only starting tag e.g.

```
if(it =~ "desired starting tag){
     then keep the value in list
}
```

But I don't know how to do this for entire table block in groovy elegant way. I have heard about 3rd part libraries such as dom4j, nekohtml etc etc, but it is my assurance that Groovy itself can handle this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (but you need to use a third party lib to be able to parse HTML as XML)

```
// The 3rd party bit
@Grab( 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1' )
import groovy.xml.*

def parser = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()

// Needed for the serialize method below to avoid html:table prefixed names
parser.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false )

def tab = new XmlSlurper( parser ).parse( 'http://weather.am' )           // Parse the HTML
                                  .'**'                                   // Search the tree
                                  .findAll { it.name() == 'table' }       // Find tables
                                  .findAll { it.@class == 'pop_up_list' } // With this class
                                  .find()                                 // Just return the first one

// Then print out what we found
println XmlUtil.serialize( tab )
```

If you want to get the location names from this table (as an example), you can do:

```
// For each `tr` in the table, collect the first `td` text
def locations = tab.tr.collect { it.td[ 0 ].text() }
// Print out the items
locations.each { println it }
```

Which will print:

```
Երևան
Շիրակ
Կոտայք
Գեղարքունիք
Լոռի
Տավուշ
Արագածոտնի լեռներ
Արագածոտնի նախալեռներ
Արարատ
Արմավիր
Վայոց ձորի լեռներ
Վայոց ձորի նախալեռներ
Սյունիքի հովիտներ
Սյունիքի նախալեռն
Արցախ
Ջավախք
```